# python datetime delta inaccuracy - Sidereal period

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

In python datatime module I noticed a gap. Datetime does leap year adjustment automatically, using sidereal year length.

How to achieve scientific accuracy in these date calculations?

The difference is expected to be exactly `200`, but it is `199.99377806650291`

This is messing up the accuracy of the application.

Sidereal year days = `365.256363004`

Expected difference is exactly 200 using 365.256363004.
`2103-1903 = 200`

```
>>> s = datetime.datetime(1903,1,1,0,0,0)
>>> s.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")
'Thursday, 01. January 1903 12:00AM'
>>> 
>>> e = datetime.datetime(2103,1,1,0,0,0)
>>> e.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")
'Monday, 01. January 2103 12:00AM'
>>> 
>>> e-s
datetime.timedelta(days=73049)
>>> s-e
datetime.timedelta(days=-73049)
>>>
```

Error -

datetime calculated time delta `73049` days.

I think time delta should return `200 * 365.256363004 = 73051.2726008` days.

`73049 / 365.256363004 = 199.99377806650291`

`200 - 199.99377806650291 = 0.0062219334971` #expected - calculated = error

`365.256363004 * 24 * 60 = 525969.16272576 minutes` #minutes in a Sidereal year

`365.256363004 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 31558149.7635456 seconds` #seconds in a Sidereal year

`365.256363004 * 0.0062219334971 = 2.272600800003505 days` #error in days

`525969.16272576 * 0.0062219334971 = 3272.545152005046885 minutes` #error in minutes

`31558149.7635456 * 0.0062219334971 = 196352.709120302813103 seconds` #error in seconds

It seems datetime is using `365.25` instead of all significant digits `365.256363004`.
`0.256363004 * 4 = 1.025452016 - 1 = 0.025452016` is ignored over leap year adjustments, not tracked by datetime that is causing error in scientific calculations.

Comment: @esqew Seems correct that floating point math can cause it. But the error too big  for floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: So what did you expect to get instead of `datetime.timedelta(days=73049)`? It seems correct to me that the difference between any two points in time which are both 12:00AM in the same time zone is a whole number of days.

Comment: @mkrieger1 In my code I add a series of periods using `datetime delta`. At the end of addition of a series the end date is supposed to be `2103,1,1` but it overflows, goes beyond, error accumulates. Though the span is exactly 200 years.

Comment: "Sidereal year days = 365.256363004" is not a fact that is the least bit relevant to `datetime`.  Each year is *exactly* 365 or 366 days long; you'd have to use a timespan in the billions of years (which I think is more than `datetime` can handle) for the calculated year length to match that number.

Comment: @mkrieger1 This is just a terminal output to show the large error of 2.27 days over 200 years. I think timedelta should return `200 *  365.256363004= 73051.2726008` days for this small scope of 200 years.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That extra `0.256363004` adds to a full day after 4 years as leap year. datetime has inbuilt leap year calculation.  Without `365.256363004` it wont be able to do leap year adjustments.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, that is where the extra leap year day comes from. And it is more than a day. May be that is causing this error if that difference is not tracked.

Comment: You can find the source code that does the calculation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_pydatetime.py#L2235). Basically, the datetime fields are converted into a serial representation (ordinal days in Python's datetime), that takes the leap years of the proleptic Gregorian calendar into account. Then the calculation of the difference becomes a trivial subtraction.

Comment: I took the freedom to re-open. If your goal is to do astronomical calculations, Python's datetime module might not be the adequate choice. There are third-party libraries however, e.g. [ephem](https://pypi.org/project/ephem/), which could be better-suited.

Answer (score 1):

The number of days being returned is exactly correct:

```
>>> def is_leap(y):
    return (y % 4 == 0) and ((y % 100 != 0) or (y % 400 == 0))

>>> sum(366 if is_leap(y) else 365 for y in range(1903,2103))
73049
```

The problem is your expectation that a year is exactly 365.256363004 days.  It is trivially easy to prove that this is not the case.  Calculate the difference between any two consecutive years, and the difference will be either 365 days or 366 days.  It will *never* be a non-integer.

Comment: There is a point in saying that, on average over many years, a year has 365.25... days (if roughly every 4th year has 366 instead of 365 days). I'm not sure if that number which would be relevant in this context is 365.256363004.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the number from the question appears to be the accepted number of days in a sidereal year, plus a small error.  But I can't see how the number of days in a sidereal year would be relevant in any context I can think of.  One thing for sure, Python is not messing up the math.

Comment: @MarkRansom It seems datetime is using `365.25` instead of `365.256363004`, so `0.256363004 * 4 = 1.025452016 - 1 = 0.025452016` is ignored, not tracked by datetime that is causing the error. When I used `3.25` instead of `365.256363004` my error went away, I got perfect 200 year increment. How can they ignore `365.256363004` that is the scientific value, it must be considered for app to scientifically accurate.

Comment: @Majoris that number is the number of days in the sidereal year. That definition of a year is not useful for making calendar calculations, that's why the datetime module does not use it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, The calendar system itself does not account for extra period of `0.025452016`  after the leap year adjustment. So Datetime doesn't implement it either. It makes datetime scientifically inaccurate. My program is a scientific program. Accuracy is important. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_year

Comment: @Majoris how is datetime scientifically inaccurate when it gives you the exact number of days?  Somehow you expect a sidereal year and a calendar year to be equal, and it should be clear by now that they are not.  The number 199.99377806650291 you are obtaining is correct, use it and be happy.

Comment: @MarkRansom `tropical year = 365.2421897 days`
`sidereal year = 365.256363004 days`
The Gregorian calendar is based on a cycle of 400 years, or 146097 days.
`146097 days / 400 years = 365.2425 days`
`365.256363004 - 365.2425 = 0.013863004 days error`. For my purpose I need sidereal calculations for astronomical use, since Datetime does calculations for the purpose of Gregorian calendar. The difference between sidereal days and Gregorian days is causing inaccuracy. If Datetime had a switch for sidereal mode, it would solve the confusion.

Comment: @Majoris if you feel so strongly about this, there's nothing preventing you from creating your own module that works in sidereal days.